# keeping URL domain the same when pointing A record to a hosting account

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, shared-hosting, dns-hosting

I have a new WordPress website and a legacy billing system. For technical reasons, they cannot be on the same hosting plan. The hosting account for billing (and the original abc.com website) also manages DNS and mail.

I'm trying to incorporate the new website under the same domain, eg. abc.com (website, on a different hosting account) and billing.abc.com (billing). I assume the answer is having a different A record for abc.com.

I currently have a CPanel shared hosting account to use for the website (but can upgrade if necessary). How would I set this up in CPanel, so that the URLs work properly? Do I need a dedicated IP and then add the domain as an add-on domain?

Thanks

Comment: Just a word of warning: The hosting company could forbid you do set A records. It depends on what they configured in the back-end. Check first in cPanel if you can set new A records.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,I would just set an A record for Billing.example.com to the Billing server. Then keep the example.com A record the same and it will work how you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you control DNS through cpanel, add an A record for both abc.com and billing.abc.com pointing to their IP's.

You will then need to configure the webserver for each domain aswell. If both accounts are using cpanel, this should be trivial. Sounds like you know what is needed, but are looking for re-assurance. More details may be required if you want specifics.

Comment: Thanks - I do have a sense of what is needed, I've just never done it before (and the client wants assurance that their domain will be intact in the website's URL before changing the DNS). I guess I just want to know what I need on abc.com's end to have the proper URL - maybe an account with a dedicated IP, a certain .htaccess setting?..

Comment: No, shared will work as it can get the hostheaders. just point the A to the shared IP and setup billing.example.com as a host header and your good.

Comment: Like Jacob said, the server gets the domain from the browser. Just set up the host like you normally would, and while it wont work until DNS is changed, it wont cause any errors before DNS works either so its safe to do prior to the switch.